# Want to bind all database from SQL Server to dropdownlist (want list of all databse in dropdownlist)

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public partial class DropDownList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dropdownticket();
        }
    }

    string strsqlcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconn"].ConnectionString;

    protected void dropdownticket()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strsqlcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SYS.databases", sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet sd = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(sd);
            Dropdownlist1.DataSource = sd;
            Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "";
            Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "";
            Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
            Dropdownlist1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I can not find the database list in dropdownlist.

Comment: dear please explain , mean you want your all database in you sql server in dropdown list and then when you select database from the dropdown you want to query this database let me know then i will send you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify which `column` should be assigned to the `DropDownList` from the `SELECT` query

`name` is the column which specify `databsename` from your `SELECT` query.

Try This:

```
        Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "name";
        Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "name";
```

Comment: Dear All,

Thank you for you valuable time i have found 2 issue 
1)  SqlConnection  issue 
2) Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "name";
        Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "name";


i have correct it working fine it is now closed

Answer (score 1):

You need specify which column should be assigned to the DropDownList from the SELECT query that column you have to add in DataTextField and DataValueField field of Dropdownlist.

```
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "name";
    Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "name";
```